# How do I make a embed larger in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Currently have this code to print an embed:

```
@client.command()
async def draw(ctx, dailycoin1, dailycoin2, dailycoin3, dailycoin4, dailycoin5, dailycoin6, day, month, year, prize):

  
  embed=discord.Embed(title=f'{prize} Jackpot!')
  embed.set_author(name=f'Draw for {day} {month} {year}')
  embed.add_field(name=f'{dailycoin1} {dailycoin2} {dailycoin3} {dailycoin4} {dailycoin5} {dailycoin6}', value=False, inline=True)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It displays the embed like this, how do I make it larger overall?

[image]

Also how do I get rid of he text that says "False" at the bottom?

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Have you tried using `embed.description` instead of `add_field`? It only takes one argument (a string)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know I do not think it is possible to define the size of the embed because since it can be viewed on other devices there is a standard size.

As for the false writing I believe it is the value in the:

embed.add_field(name=f'{dailycoin1} {dailycoin2} {dailycoin3} {dailycoin4} {dailycoin5} {dailycoin6}', value="**False**", inline=True)

So the final result would be:

```
embed.add_field(name=f'{dailycoin1} {dailycoin2} {dailycoin3} {dailycoin4} {dailycoin5} {dailycoin6}', value="\u200b", inline=True)
```

Comment: When I remove `value=False`, I get this error `TypeError: add_field() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'value'` @Klayser

Comment: @AlternateAccount 
If you put the value of value equal to "", what happens?

Comment: @Klayer It says I can't leave the field empty

Comment: not empty just write value = "" @AlternateAccount, test the final result in my answer

Comment: Still says empty for some reason

Comment: @AlternateAccount 
I found a solution after a couple of tries, 
instead of putting only the quotation marks you have to put this:  **value = "\u200b"**

This work fine for me

Comment: ah ok thx @Klayser

Comment: @AlternateAccount maybe consider accepting the solution